# Understanding the pseudocode in the Donald B. Johnson's algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, cycle, pseudocode

Does anyone know the [Donald B. Johnson's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm), which enumerates all the elementary circuits (cycles) in a **directed** graph?

I have the paper he had published in 1975, but I cannot understand the pseudocode.

My goal is to implement this algorithm in Java.

Some questions I have, for example, is what is the matrix A<sub>k</sub> it refers to. In the pseudocode, it mentions that

```
Ak:=adjacency structure of strong component K with least 
    vertex in subgraph of G induced by {s,s+1,....n};
```

Does that mean I have to implement another algorithm that finds the A<sub>k</sub> matrix?

Another question is what the following means?

```
begin logical f;
```

Does also the line `"logical procedure CIRCUIT (integer value v);"` mean that the circuit procedure returns a logical variable? In the pseudocode also has the line "`CIRCUIT := f;`". What does this mean?

It would be great if someone could translate this 1970's pseudocode to a more modern type of pseudocode so I can understand it

In case you are interested to help but you cannot find the paper please email me at pitelk@hotmail.com and I will send you the paper.

Comment: Did you try reading the paper you linked to? It seems to have an accompanying explanation and proof.

Comment: yes i have, but still it doesnt explain the code itself, just the general idea. What i cannot understand is the pseudo code.

also i have found another link to the paper in case the first is not working   
http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf

Comment: Thanks to you all , you have taken care of the appearance of my question (made it look better; corrected spelling mistakes and changed the code i have wrote to the original of the paper -for some strange reason i couldn't just copy - paste the code so i typed it from scratch.)

Comment: `AK` refers to the edge list of the induced subgraph of vertices `VK`. A *Mathematica* demonstration (and source code) is available [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EnumeratingCyclesOfADirectedGraph/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pseudo-code is reminiscent of Algol, Pascal or Ada.

> Does that mean I have to implement another algorithm that finds the A<sub>k</sub> matrix?

A<sub>k</sub> appears to be a list of arrays of input values having the specified properties. It may be related to the corresponding [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), but it's not clear to me. I'm guessing something like this:

```
int[][] a = new int[k][n];
int[][] b = new int[k][n];
boolean[] blocked = new boolean[n];
int s;
```

> What does `logical f` mean?

This declares a local variable representing a `true` or `false` value, similar to Java's `boolean`.

> `logical procedure CIRCUIT (integer value v);`

This declares a subprogram named `CIRCUIT` having a single integer parameter `v` that is passed by value. The subprogram returns a `logical` result of `true` or `false`, and `CIRCUIT := f` assigns `f` as the result. In Java,

```
boolean circuit(int v) {
    boolean f;
    ...
    f = false;
    ...
    return f;
}
```

The keywords `begin` and `end` delimit a block scope that may be nested, so `CIRCUIT` is nested in the main block and `UNBLOCK` is nested inside of `CIRCUIT`. `:=` is assignment; `¬` is `not`; `∈` is element; `∅` is empty; `≠` is `!=`; `stack` and `unstack` suggest `push` and `pop`.

It's only a start, but I hope it helps.

Addendum: On reflection, `A` and `B` must be isomorphic.

Here's a *very literal* outline. I don't know enough about `A`, `B` & `V` to choose a better  data structure than arrays.

```
import java.util.Stack;

public final class CircuitFinding {
    static int k, n;
    int[][] a = new int[k][n];
    int[][] b = new int[k][n];
    boolean[] blocked = new boolean[n];
    int[] v = new int[k];
    int s = 1;
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    private void unblock(int u) {
        blocked[u] = false;
        for (int w : b[u]) {
            //delete w from B(u)
            if (blocked[w]) {
                unblock(w);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean circuit(int v) {
        boolean f = false;
        stack.push(v);
        blocked[v] = true;
        L1:
        for (int w : a[v]) {
            if (w == s) {
                //output circuit composed of stack followed by s;
                f = true;
            } else if (!blocked[w]) {
                if (circuit(w)) {
                    f = true;
                }
            }
        }
        L2:
        if (f) {
            unblock(v);
        } else {
            for (int w : a[v]) {
                //if (v∉B(w)) put v on B(w);
            }
        }
        v = stack.pop();
        return f;
    }

    public void main() {
        while (s < n) {
            //A:= adjacency structure of strong component K with least
            //vertex in subgraph of G induced by {s, s+ 1, n};
            if (a[k] != null) {
                //s := least vertex in V;
                for (int i : v) {
                    blocked[i] = false;
                    b[i] = null;
                }
                L3:
                circuit(s);
                s++;
            } else {
                s = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you  very much for the information. Still i was not able to make any significant progress. i will try to find out the ada or algol syntax.  Until then can you clarify to me something? the CIRCUIT := f returns the value immiadetly or just assigns tha value to be returned later? in other words it is like f = false or like return (f=false)
Thanks

Comment: The statement `CIRCUIT := f` assigns the current value of the local variable `f` as the result when the subprogram exits normally after the following statement. The assignment does not _cause_ the return; it merely precedes it. Use of the identifier `CIRCUIT` does not imply recursion, whereas `UNBLOCK` appears to be called recursively. The code strongly resembles Wirth's _Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs_: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_%2B_Data_Structures_%3D_Programs

Comment: I think after studying it again and again and with your helpful comments it starts to make sense to me. I will try to write my version of pseudo code and i will post it when it is ready!

Comment: I've added a rough outline. I look forward to your results.

Comment: Thanks for the outline .  It is very usefull, also some thing you have wrote is what i was thinking too so that means  i am the correct road. The only problem (major one) is  i cannot still understand what Vk and Ak (or better , how Vk and Ak are chosen). I have posted this question as a new tread in 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939877/help-in-the-donalds-b-johnsons-algorithm-i-cannot-understand-the-pseudo-code
If i understand this , i think i will be able to write the code to java

Comment: Now I'm a fan of educational answers

Comment: @stacker: Educational? Yes, but also a little nostalgic. :-)

Comment: @trashgod The comment was exactly one year old ;-)

Comment: @stacker: Egad! You're right; I misread the date, but thanks for the nod.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a Java implementation of this algorithm on github: https://github.com/1123/johnson. It uses the Jung2 java graph library.