# help in the Donalds B. Johnson's algorithm, i cannot understand the pseudo code (PART II)

Tags: algorithm, graph, cycle, pseudocode

i cannot understand a certain part of the paper published by Donald Johnson about finding cycles (Circuits) in a graph.

More specific i cannot understand what is the matrix Ak which is mentioned in the following line of the pseudo code :

Ak:=adjacency structure of strong component K with least 
    vertex in subgraph of G induced by {s,s+1,....n};

to make things worse some lines after is mentins  " for i in Vk do " without declaring what the Vk is...

As far i have understand we have the following:
1) in general, a strong component is a sub-graph of a graph, in which for every node of this sub-graph there is a path to any node of the sub-graph (in other words you can access any node of the sub-graph from any other node of the sub-graph)

2) a sub-graph **induced**  by a list of nodes is
 a graph containing all these nodes plus all the edges connecting these nodes.
 in paper the mathematical definition is  " F is a subgraph of G induced by W if W is subset of V and F = (W,{u,y)|u,y in W and (u,y) in E)}) where u,y are edges , E is the set of all the edges in the graph, W is a set of nodes.

3)in the code implementation the nodes are named by integer numbers 1 ... n.

4) I **suspect** that the Vk is the set of nodes of the strong component K.

now to the question. Lets say we have a graph G= (V,E) with V = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} which it can be divided into 3 strong components the SC1 = {1,4,7,8} SC2= {2,3,9} SC3 = {5,6} (and their edges)

Can anybody give me an example for s =1, s= 2, s= 5 what if going to be the Vk and Ak according to the code?

The pseudo code is in my previous question in 
[Understanding the pseudocode in the Donald B. Johnson's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908575/help-in-the-donalds-b-johnsons-algorithm-i-cannot-understand-the-pseudo-code)

and the paper can be found at 
[Understanding the pseudocode in the Donald B. Johnson's algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908575/help-in-the-donalds-b-johnsons-algorithm-i-cannot-understand-the-pseudo-code)

thank you in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works! In an [earlier iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2910186) of the [Johnson algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm), I had supposed that `A` was an [adjacency matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix). Instead, it appears to represent an [adjacency list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list). In that example, implemented below, the vertices [{a, b, c}](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) are numbered {0, 1, 2}, yielding the following circuits.

Addendum: As noted in this proposed [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1478397) and helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824734/230513), the algorithm specifies that `unblock()` should remove the element having the *value* `w`, not the element having the *index* `w`.

```
list.remove(Integer.valueOf(w));
```

Sample output:

```
0 1 0
0 1 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 2 1
1 2 0 1
1 2 1
2 0 1 2
2 0 2
2 1 0 2
2 1 2
```

By default, the program starts with `s = 0`; implementing `s := least vertex in V` as an optimization remains. A variation that produces only unique cycles is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35922906/230513).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * @see http://dutta.csc.ncsu.edu/csc791_spring07/wrap/circuits_johnson.pdf
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908575
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939877
 * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix
 * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list
 */
public final class CircuitFinding {

    final Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    final List<List<Integer>> a;
    final List<List<Integer>> b;
    final boolean[] blocked;
    final int n;
    int s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2)));
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2)));
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1)));
        CircuitFinding cf = new CircuitFinding(a);
        cf.find();
    }

    /**
     * @param a adjacency structure of strong component K with
     * least vertex in subgraph of G induced by {s, s + 1, n};
     */
    public CircuitFinding(List<List<Integer>> a) {
        this.a = a;
        n = a.size();
        blocked = new boolean[n];
        b = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
    }

    private void unblock(int u) {
        blocked[u] = false;
        List<Integer> list = b.get(u);
        for (int w : list) {
            //delete w from B(u);
            list.remove(Integer.valueOf(w));
            if (blocked[w]) {
                unblock(w);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean circuit(int v) {
        boolean f = false;
        stack.push(v);
        blocked[v] = true;
        L1:
        for (int w : a.get(v)) {
            if (w == s) {
                //output circuit composed of stack followed by s;
                for (int i : stack) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
                System.out.println(s);
                f = true;
            } else if (!blocked[w]) {
                if (circuit(w)) {
                    f = true;
                }
            }
        }
        L2:
        if (f) {
            unblock(v);
        } else {
            for (int w : a.get(v)) {
                //if (v∉B(w)) put v on B(w);
                if (!b.get(w).contains(v)) {
                    b.get(w).add(v);
                }
            }
        }
        v = stack.pop();
        return f;
    }

    public void find() {
        while (s < n) {
            if (a != null) {
                //s := least vertex in V;
                L3:
                circuit(s);
                s++;
            } else {
                s = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @stacker: I hope not! Paraphrasing Knuth: "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only tried it, not proved it correct."

Comment: @trashgod Thank you for your kind and very usefull help
@stacker basically is my a small part of my MSC dissertation but it's no problem as i have already wrote most of the code plus i use totally different structures.
I haven't tested your code but still there is a minor problem. The Ak refers to subgraph of strong components (in your example the network all an SCC .. but what happens if it can be divided in 2 SCC? how is going to be the Ak then? ) That stil remains the big question mark. My idea is that propably ( i have to test to it to check for the correctness) the Ak is the adjaceny list

Comment: of the subgraph containing the s,  but with the edges from this SCC to all the other SCCs removed . For example let {0,1,2} be your example graph which is connected to the {3,4} with an edge from 2 -> 3 then the A0, A1,A2 will be the  (already given by you) adjacency list plus the new one WITHOUT the edge from 2->3.

Comment: All the fuss about the SCC is becuase you can divide the G to smaller one hence improve the perfomance of the algorithm ( as the algorithm has a complexity O(E*C) where C=number of cycles ..which C grows 2^n where n is the number of nodes...) 
Anyway, A million thanks for your all your help!

Comment: @Pitelk: As this answer doesn't really address your question, I'd leave the question open for a time. I'll update if I get new insight.

Comment: @Trashgod: I have successfully implemented the algorithm (i still cannot believe it!!) in java using my structure. I assumed Vk is the strongly connected network containing the current node (the s variable in the case of your implementation). Your code is not working always. Depending on the network it may throw a null pointer exception. Anyway .. your help was priceless and the algorithm really helped me to understant (plus i learned about Stack) and i would like to have you in my thanks list of my dissertation project if it is ok with you (i would need your name though.. :)  ) 
Many thanks

Comment: @Pitelk: Excellent; an up-vote is always welcomed. :-) I think you're supposed to cite the relevant StackOverflow question(s), but my user page is fairly transparent. http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.5/

Comment: As @Chitr mentions in an answer below, the output contains cyclic permutations, e.g. 0-1-0 and 1-0-1. This is because the step "adjacency structure of strong component K with least vertex in subgraph of G induced by {s, s+1, ..., n};" basically means that every vertex less than s should be removed from the adjacency list for that run. That will remove cycles including these vertices, and thus just keep distinct cycles.

Comment: @Gedde: Correct; as noted above, that "optimization remains"; one [approach](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12405839/230513) was deleted by its owner; please let me know if you add an answer expanding on Chitr's observation.

Comment: @thrashgod: Yeah, it's just that this was the key part of the question and imho it's not only an optimization but a very important step of the algorithm. Without this part you'll not find *distinct* elementary circuits, and it is quite expensive to remove duplicates after the run. It really degrades the efficiency of the algorithm. I'll see whether I'll add an answer later on. It is basically just pruning out all vertices that are less than `s` from the `Ak`

Comment: @Gedde: I've added a [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35922906/230513), citing it above; note code fix in [revision 7](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2951908/revisions).

Answer (score 2):

The following variation produces unique cycles. Based on this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2951908/230513), it is adapted from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12405839/230513) supplied by [@user1406062](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1406062/user1406062).

Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908575
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939877
 * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix
 * @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list
 */
public final class CircuitFinding {

    final Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
    final Map<Integer, List<Integer>> a;
    final List<List<Integer>> b;
    final boolean[] blocked;
    final int n;
    Integer s;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> a = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2)));
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 2)));
        a.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 1)));
        CircuitFinding cf = new CircuitFinding(a);
        cf.find();
    }

    /**
     * @param a adjacency structure of strong component K with least vertex in
     * subgraph of G induced by {s, s + 1, n};
     */
    public CircuitFinding(List<List<Integer>> A) {
        this.a = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>(A.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < A.size(); i++) {
            this.a.put(i, new ArrayList<Integer>());
            for (int j : A.get(i)) {
                this.a.get(i).add(j);
            }
        }
        n = a.size();
        blocked = new boolean[n];
        b = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            b.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        }
    }

    private void unblock(int u) {
        blocked[u] = false;
        List<Integer> list = b.get(u);
        for (int w : list) {
            //delete w from B(u);
            list.remove(Integer.valueOf(w));
            if (blocked[w]) {
                unblock(w);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean circuit(int v) {
        boolean f = false;
        stack.push(v);
        blocked[v] = true;
        L1:
        for (int w : a.get(v)) {
            if (w == s) {
                //output circuit composed of stack followed by s;
                for (int i : stack) {
                    System.out.print(i + " ");
                }
                System.out.println(s);
                f = true;
            } else if (!blocked[w]) {
                if (circuit(w)) {
                    f = true;
                }
            }
        }
        L2:
        if (f) {
            unblock(v);
        } else {
            for (int w : a.get(v)) {
                //if (v∉B(w)) put v on B(w);
                if (!b.get(w).contains(v)) {
                    b.get(w).add(v);
                }
            }
        }
        v = stack.pop();
        return f;
    }

    public void find() {
        s = 0;
        while (s < n) {
            if (!a.isEmpty()) {
                //s := least vertex in V;
                L3:
                for (int i : a.keySet()) {
                    b.get(i).clear();
                    blocked[i] = false;
                }
                circuit(s);
                a.remove(s);
                for (Integer j : a.keySet()) {
                    if (a.get(j).contains(s)) {
                        a.get(j).remove(s);
                    }
                }
                s++;
            } else {
                s = n;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0 1 0
0 1 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 1 0
1 2 1
```

All cycles, for reference:

```
0 1 0
0 1 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 1 0
1 0 1
1 0 2 1
1 2 0 1
1 2 1
2 0 1 2
2 0 2
2 1 0 2
2 1 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had sumbitted an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1478397) request to @trashgod's code to fix the exception thrown in `unblock()`. Essentially, the algorithm states that the element `w` (which is *not* an index) is to be removed from the list. The code above used `list.remove(w)`, which treats `w` as an index.

My [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1478397) request was rejected! Not sure why, because I have tested the above with my modification on a network of 20,000 nodes and 70,000 edges and it doesn't crash.

I have also modified Johnson's algorithm to be more adapted to undirected graphs. If anybody wants these modifications please contact me.

Below is my code for `unblock()`.

```
private void unblock(int u) {
    blocked[u] = false;
    List<Integer> list = b.get(u);
    int w;
    for (int iw=0; iw < list.size(); iw++) {
        w = Integer.valueOf(list.get(iw));
        //delete w from B(u);
        list.remove(iw);
        if (blocked[w]) {
            unblock(w);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for spotting this; I've updated my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2951908/230513) similarly. The edit request may have looked like an attempt to circumvent the comment threshold, but it's a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

@trashgod, your sample output contains cycle which are cyclic permutation.
For example 0-1-0 and 1-0-1 are same 
Actually the output should contains only 5 cycle i.e.
        0 1 0,
        0 2 0,
        0 1 2 0,
        0 2 1 0,
        1 2 1,

Johnson paper explain what a cycle is:
'Two elementary circuits are distinct if one is not a cyclic permutation of the other.
'
One can also check wolfram page: This also output 5 cycle for the same input.

http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/EnumeratingCyclesOfADirectedGraph/