# how to bind arraylist in list view in java

Tags: java, swing, multidimensional-array, jtable

i have an arrylist and a list view.i need to bind the arraylist to listview.
is there 2 dimensional arraylist in java. if so,how to bind datas in arraylist.How to bind it in a JTable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***...is there 2 dimensional arraylist in java...*** - Yes

```
// T is the type of your data.
List<ArrayList<T>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<T>>();
```

---

**UPDATE**

To use the data from the `ArrayList` in the `JList` you need to convert it to an array of objects. For example:

```
JList jlist = new JList(list.toArray());
```

Comment: how to access the datas from row and colums.how to bind it?

Comment: how to bind arraylist to JList?

Answer (score 2):

[JTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) know two kinds of 2D Arrays  `Object [][]` or `Vector<Vector<Object>>` that are directly accesible, some examples about [JTable](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Table.htm)

Comment: +1 Is this characteristic of the [`DefaultTableModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)?

Comment: yes or no too, I never see some differencie between set Array/Vector, to the myTable (data[][], header[]) or standard way to stick Abstract/DefaultTableModel, by permormance issue (my view) I'm not fans for Set or List family wraped into TableModel, +1 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Java supports multi-dimensional data structures such as `List<List<…>>`. `ArrayList` is just one implementation of the [`List`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, and each dimensions may use a different implementation. This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939877/help-in-the-donalds-b-johnsons-algorithm-i-cannot-understand-the-pseudo-code/2951908#2951908) illustrates `List<List<Integer>>`.

The two dimensional case may require nothing more elaborate than `List<Record>`, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064027/sorting-2d-array-of-string-in-java/5064357#5064357); or `List<Value>`, shown [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table) in the context of an `AbstractTableModel`. See [*Creating a Table Model*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data) for additional details.

Comment: ArrayList<String > arl = new ArrayList<String >();.....Object obj = arl.clone();.... final JTable table = new JTable(data, obj);              give an error

Comment: @KIRAN: I don't understand your code. What error? You might update your question with an [sscce](http://sscce.org); code in comments is hard to read. I see both @camickr and @Catalina Island addressed your binding question.

Answer (score 1):

> how to bind it in listview

`JList` has a `AbstractListModel` that works a lot like how `JTable` has a `AbstractTableModel`. If that's what you want, the examples in ["How to Use Lists"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) may help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what a "listview" is. But if you want to display data from an ArrayList in a JTable then you need to create a custom TableModel. [List Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/24/list-table-model/) is one implementation that you can use.