# 2D Array that can hold multiple values with no limits

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am quite new to java currently working on a not-so-simple web browser application in which I would like to record a permanent history file with a 2D array setup with 3 columns containing "Date Viewed", "URL", "How many times this URL has been viewed before".

Currently I have a temporary solution that only saves "URL" which is also used for "Back, Foward" features using an ArrayList.

```
private List tempHistory = new ArrayList();
```

I am reading through the Java documentation but I cannot put together a solution, unless I am missing the obvious there is no 2D array as flexible a ArrayList like in Python?

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList>`

Comment: `List<List<…>>`, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2951908/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description it doesn't sound like you need a 2D array. You just have one dimension -- but of complex data types, right?

So define a `HistoryItem` class or something with a `Date` property for date viewed, `URL` for URL, `int` for view count.

Then you just want a `List<HistoryItem> history = new ArrayList<HistoryItem>()`.

The reason I don't think you really want a 2D array-like thing is that it could only hold one data type, and you clearly have several data types at work here, like a date and a count. But if you really want a table-like abstraction, try Guava's [Table](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html).

Comment: Thank You, I think your approach sounds most suited, but to clarify my understanding, I simple set up a class to store there three variables, designate them to a single line and save to a binary file instead of requiring an array? My concern was maintaining the data types to easily sort after they have been loaded. I will give this a try and report result, thank you.

Comment: You mention several different converns. If you want to save these objects to a binary file, look into `Serializable`. If you want them to be sortable, look into implementing `Comparable` or make a `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no built-in 2D array type in Java (unless you use primitive arrays).

You *could* just use a list of lists (`List<List>`) - however, I think it is almost always better to use a custom type that you put into the list. In your case, you'd create a class `HistoryEntry` (with fields for "Date viewed", URL etc.), and use `List<HistoryEntry>`. That way, you get all the benefits a proper type gives you (typechecking, completion in an IDE, ability to put methods into the class etc.).

Answer (score 0):

How do you plan to browse the history then? If you want to search the history for each url later on then ArrayList approach might not be efficient.

I would rather prefer a Map with URL as key.

```
Map<Url,UrlHistory> browseHistory = new HahMap<Url,UrlHistory> ();
```

UrlHistory will contains all the fields you want to associate with a url like no. of times page was accessed and all.