# Pathfinding in adjacency matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, shortest-path, adjacency-matrix

Given an adjacency matrix, how would you find the shortest paths between two nodes while traversing to each point at least once and returning how many moves it takes?

**Example**

Given this array

```
int[][] points = { { 0, 1 },{ 0, 2 },{ 1, 2 },{ 1, 3 },{ 3, 4 } };
```

I make an adjacent matrix like so...

```
     0    1    2    3    4   
0   [0]  [1]  [1]  [0]  [0] 
1   [1]  [0]  [1]  [1]  [0]  
2   [1]  [1]  [0]  [0]  [0] 
3   [0]  [1]  [0]  [0]  [1]
4   [0]  [0]  [0]  [1]  [0]
```

The shortest path from 0 - 4 is (0-2)(2-1)(1-3)(3-4) and counts to be 4 moves.

I really have no idea how to go any further. Possibly a minimum spanning tree solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path; take your pick.

Comment: Traversing to each point at least once -> Sounds similar to a [Hamiltonian path](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path), which is not an easy problem to solve efficiently.

Comment: [Johnson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2939877/230513).

Comment: @trashgod, but we need to visit every vertex at least once. Johnsons algorithm runs in poly time, but it seems this may be related to some NP Hard problems (not quite if all edge weights are 1). Maybe im missing something though.

Comment: Assume all edge weights are 1. @tigger

Comment: This sounds simpler than the Hamiltonian Path problem (since we can visit vertices multiple times -> deciding whether such a path exists can be done by checking the graph for connectivity). It doesn't actually feel simpler though.

Comment: @G.Bach But if our algorithm returns a path of size |V| - 1 (over all pairs of O(n^2) verts), isn't that answering decidability version of Hamiltonian path, or am I missing something?

Comment: @tigger I didn't think of that, you are correct, this is then at least as difficult as the HP problem. But I think it would be clearer to say that if an HP exists, any algorithm solving mjenkins's problem must return an HP.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is NP Hard by reduction to Hamiltonian Path Problem as suggested by Dukeling. Suppose we have a poly time algorithm X to solve this problem. Then that means we can ask X the question of finding a minimum length path between any 2 vertices which visits all other vertices on the way to the end.

Now since we need to visit all vertices at least once, this means that the minimum length of such a path is (|V| - 1). So if our algorithm gives us a path of size (|V| - 1), we have answered the decidability problem of Hamiltonian path in poly time because we may run our algorithm X on all pairs of vertices (of which there are O(n^2)) in poly time as well.

There may be a way to use dynamic programming / recursion, but I cannot prove it is poly time. The shortest path from s to t, that visits all vertices can be computed by looking at the graph G/{s}, and ask given i \in Neighbors(s), what the shortest path from i to t is. Then we know that the shortest path from s to t, must be equal to s appended to one of its neighbors (specifically the one that leads to the shortest path to t).

Comment: It shouldn't be considering this was a assignment for class. Was* meaning that its already turned in. I'm just trying to figure out how to do it for a learning experience.

Comment: Okay, I must be missing something. I'll have to think further. Can you see what I my argument is missing? That might help us find the right course of action.