# Is there a JavaFX element for mapping elements?

Tags: java, javafx, user-controls

I am looking for a solution to map GUI elements (see drawing) in JavaFX with drawing. Is there a JavaFX element to do that? Or another possibility to achieve something alike?

[image]

The goal is to get a mapping like `[1->A,B , 2->D , 4->C , 5->C]`—I hope you get the idea. Sorry for this quite unspecific question, but any hint is appreciated.

Comment: you want to map with drawing you mean?Have a look at this https://monograff76.wordpress.com/2015/03/16/drag-and-drop-in-javafx-linking-nodes-with-cubic-curves-part-i/

Comment: You may be looking for an [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2951908/230513).

Comment: I am not aware of any component that would perfectly satisfy your needs. However, take a look at https://jankoehnlein.github.io/FXDiagram/index.html since it seems to have what you need and more.